# Error: ambiguous overload for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' and '<unnamed-signed:128>')

Tags: c++, c++11

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>

template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto sum(const T1 &v1, const T2 &v2) -> decltype(v1 + v2)
{
    return v1 + v2;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << sum(12, 123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the compiler's complaint:

`[Error] ambiguous overload for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' and '<unnamed-signed:128>')`

When I changed the seconed argument of sum to 12, this code compiled without complaint.

Comment: I'm not sure the compiler can handle numerical literals of that size...

Comment: Not many systems/C/C++ implementations offer a 128bit type. As your question seems to assume this exists, you might want to add info regarding your compiler and system.

Comment: you should also get a warning about integer constant being too large (g++), or, in clang, `error: integer constant is larger than the largest unsigned  integer type`

Comment: Should the error message be "programmer has hit his head on the number pad - please help him"

Comment: @EdHeal "Need more helmets error" of course ;)